# Typescript: Add empty string to an array

Tags: javascript, arrays, angular, typescript

I have an array of strings and in Input set method after checking some condition I want to add empty string

```
public tableData: any[] = [];
 @Input()
     set maxLengthArray(value) {
        this._maxLengthArray=value;
        while (some condtion) {
            this.tableData.push('');
            someValue--;
        }
     }
```

Reason I want to add empty string is, I'm displaying tableData values in a table  and want to display empty rows for empty strings. But empty strings are not getting added into the array. How to add it? Please suggest

Comment: Is `some condtion` ever true? Did you try it without the loop entirely?

Comment: @Ryan while condition is working properly and its entering the loop

Comment: `public tableData: Array<any> = new Array<any>();`

Answer (score 0):

You can use ES6 Spread operator to add an empty string in array on some condition like this:

```
   let data = [] 
   if(someCondition === true){
     data = [...data, '']
    };

    console.log(data)
```

[image]

Comment: No. Its not adding the  empty string into the template